# How can I continue my loop after calling a method within it?

Tags: java

I have my loop from the main class here

```
do {

     System.out.println("Awaiting new action");
     command_string = input.next();
     main.Commands(command_string);

       }
    while (!input.next().equals("exit"));
```

The user string inputted is then run through a separate loop in a method called Commands. shown here

```
    public void Commands(String commandinput)
{
 if (commandinput.equals("inv") || 
     commandinput.equals("help")||
     commandinput.equals("exit"))
 {
   if (commandinput.equals("inv"))
   {
      System.out.println("You have a total of " + mainsave.totalitems + " items");
      inventoryGrid();
   }
    if (commandinput.equals("help"))
   {
      System.out.println("[[[COMMAND LIST]]]\n" +
                         "Help -> Opens this menu\n" + 
                         "Inv  -> Views your current inventory\n" +
                         "Exit -> Exits the application\n");

   }
   if (commandinput.equals("exit"))
   {
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        System.exit(0);
   }
 }
 else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid command. Use the command 'help' to access command list");
    }
```

The method outputs everything correctly but in console you have to input something to continue the loop.
So my question is how can i start the loop again without typing something first?
I.e. print "Awaiting new action" directly after the method prints its stuff

Comment: @srv_sud There is a `do-while`...?

Comment: @srv_sud You are correct, but the question never used a standard while loop, so I don't know why you suggested using a do-while when it was already used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
while (!input.next().equals("exit"));
```

to

```
while (!command_string.equals("exit"));
```

Comment: actually it's not the case

Comment: Really? It looks to me like he calls the scanners next() method again in the while condition, which of course will wait for a new input instead of using the already entered one.

Comment: if user enters first time "exit" then your method will call the method `main.Commands(command_string)` once atleast

Comment: yep, true, I just meant that exit command calls System.exit and does not reach while condition, so it could be replaced with while (true)

Comment: This works! Thanks so much. Im new here and the response time is incredible.

Comment: AdamSkywalker... yeah, i didn't see that one. your right of course that the while condition will never be false (because the jvm will exit first)... So a simple while(true) would have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. this will exit once when user enters `"exit"` at first Iteration of loop.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Awaiting new action");
    command_string = input.nextLine();

      //break the loop even user enter "exit" in first Iteration.
    if(command_string.equals("exit")) 
        break;            
    main.Commands(command_string);
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `input.next()` by `input.nextLine` and don't call it twice since you will need to type twice  then :) instead use the already defined string variable `command_string`

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        System.out.println("Awaiting new action");
        command_string = input.nextLine();
        Commands(command_string);

    } while (!command_string.equals("exit"));
    System.out.println("bye");
}
```